# Transforming spring-ws implementation to spring-integration-ws implementation

Tags: spring-ws, spring-integration, spring-jms

I have an implementation of web service (server side) using spring-ws. I would like to change my code to use spring-integration-ws (ws:inbound-gateway and channels). I have tried examples but still not sure if it is possible to transform my implementation. In short my I am using @Endpoint, @PayloadRoot, PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping and JMS (as transport). Please find below my implementation:

**The endpoint class (MyEndpoint.java):**

```
@Endpoint
public class MyEndpoint {
    @PayloadRoot(localPart="getUserRequest", namespace="http://play.zahid.springint/Jibx")
    public GetUserResponse getUserResponse(GetUserRequest request){
        log.info("Start getUserResponse " + request);
        GetUserResponse response = new GetUserResponse();

        User user = new User();
        user.setFirstName(request.getFirstName());
        user.setLastName(request.getFirstName() + " Last");
        response.setUser(user);

        log.info("End getUserResponse " + response);
        return response;
    }

    @PayloadRoot(localPart="sayHiUserRequest", namespace="http://play.zahid.springint/Jibx")
    public SayHiResponse sayHiUserResponse(SayHiUserRequest request){
        log.info("Start sayHiUserResponse " + request);
        SayHiUserResponse response = new SayHiUserResponse();

        response.setResponse("Hi " + request.getFirstName() + " " + request.getLastName());

        log.info("End sayHiUserResponse " + response);
        return response;
    }   
}
```

**The spring xml file (applicationContext.xml):**

```
<bean id="listenerContainer"
        class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="mqCachedConnectionFactory" />
        <property name="destination" ref="defaultDestination" />
        <property name="messageListener">
            <bean class="org.springframework.ws.transport.jms.WebServiceMessageListener">
                <property name="messageFactory" ref="messageFactory"/>
                <property name="messageReceiver" ref="messageReceiver" />
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="1" />
        <property name="acceptMessagesWhileStopping" value="false" />
        <property name="recoveryInterval" value="10000" />
        <property name="cacheLevelName" value="CACHE_CONSUMER" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="messageFactory" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory" />    

    <bean id="messageReceiver" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.server.SoapMessageDispatcher">
        <property name="endpointAdapters">
            <list>
                <bean id="endpointAdapter" class="org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.GenericMarshallingMethodEndpointAdapter">
                    <constructor-arg ref="marshaller" />
                </bean>
            </list>
        </property>         
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping" />
```

For simplicity purpose I have removed the unnecessary codes and xml configuration.

**Is there anyway to keep my endpoint class (MyEndpoint.java) as it is and use spring-integration-ws support (ws:inbound-gateway and channel)?**

Let me know if you need any more information.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Is there anyway to keep my endpoint class (MyEndpoint.java) as it is and use spring-integration-ws support (ws:inbound-gateway and channel)?

Yes you can.

I'll try to explain a simple integration-ws implementation for your situation:

**applicationContext.xml:**

```
<bean id="endpointMappings"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ListFactoryBean"
        lazy-init="true">
        <property name="sourceList">
            <list>
                <ref bean="uriEndpointMapping"/>
            </list>
        </property>
</bean>

<bean id="uriEndpointMapping"
        class="org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.UriEndpointMapping"
        p:defaultEndpoint-ref="ws-inbound-gateway">
        <property name="mappings">
            <props>
                <prop key="${yourEndPointUrl}">ws-inbound-gateway</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
</bean>

<int-ws:inbound-gateway id="ws-inbound-gateway"
                        request-channel="ws-request-channel"
                        reply-channel="ws-response-channel"
                        error-channel="ws-error-channel"
                        marshaller="marshaller"
                        unmarshaller="marshaller"/>

<int:channel id="ws-request-channel"/>
<int:channel id="ws-response-channel"/>
<int:channel id="ws-error-channel"/>

<int:chain input-channel="ws-request-channel" output-channel="ws-response-channel">
    <int:service-activator ref="yourBean" method="getUserResponse"/>
</int:chain>
```

There are some points here. 
You need to define a bean, MyEndpoint type, I named it *yourBean* here.
*yourEndPointUrl* defines your end point URL for *getUserResponse* method.
I've defined service-activator inside a chain, you can add logging or another thing inside this chain to enrich your handling mechanism.
You also need to have a router for routing your requests in to different methods of your bean.